# In c++ how do you declare a binary semaphore?

Tags: c++, semaphore

I am trying to declare a binary semaphore in C++.
Is there a way to do it by using Semaphore X; ?
What is the header you need to include?

Sorry ... I am using unix g++

Answer (score 4):

The C++ language and standard libraries do not have any concept of semaphores, or even threads.  The answer depends entirely on what platform you're working on; for instance, the Windows and Linux system APIs have support for semaphores.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: "will have", strictly speaking. It's still only a draft, albeit a final one!

Answer (score 2):

Since C++2003 will be around for a while have a look at `Boost.Thread`. You won't find a semaphore in there, but that is probably too low level for what you are trying to do anyway.

Comment: A "binary semaphore" is very similar to a mutex, which is probably what the OP wants. So Boost.Thread should do fine. +1

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler you're using implements (at least the threading part of) the C++11 standard library, you'd use `std::mutex X;`, or possibly `std::recursive_mutex X;`, `std::timed_mutex X;` or `std::recursive_timed_mutex X;`, depending on what capabilities you want (lacking a statement to the indicate otherwise, I'd guess you want `std::mutex`).

With an older library, you'd probably want to use the `pthreads` equivalent. If you need to support Windows (which doesn't include pthreads natively), you could use Anthony Williams's [pthreads-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) package. This has two good points: first, it's native to Posix and Posix-like systems (e.g., Linux), and second, although it uses slightly different names, the basic idea is almost like what's in the C++11 standard library, it should be pretty easy to change to that when your compiler supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20 this is now possible in standard C++. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore for reference and an example. It is supported by compilers: g++ 11, clang 11, msvc standard library 19.28

Comment: I am trying to use std::counting_semaphore and I have updated VS to 16.10.3 so I am asuming MSVC version is at least 19.28, and when I include <semaphore>  I still get an error "std has no member coutning_semaphore"

Comment: I'm using VS preview, Version 16.11.0 Preview 3.0. I guess that explains the difference.